# How can I access another server with Python?

Tags: python, ssh

I have two servers, and one updates with a DNSBL of 100k domains every 15 minutes. I want to process these domains through a Python script with information from Safebrowsing, Siteadvisor, and other services. Unfortunately, the server with the DNSBL is rather slow. Is there a way I can transfer the files over from the other server with SSH in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just files (and directories) you are transferring, why not just use [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) over ssh (in a bash script perhaps). A proven, mature method.

Or you could mount the remote filesystem (over ssh) into your own filesystem using [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) (fuse) and then use something like [pyrobocopy](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/231501-python-robocopier-advanced-directory-synchronizati/) (implementing a basic version of rsync functionality in Python) to transfer the files.

If you don't need *incremental* copying, you could go the simple route: mount the remote filesystem using sshfs (link above) and then use [shutil.copytree](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) to copy the correct directory.

Or yet another option: implement it using the [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) Python ssh module.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with just the python standard library?

Comment: Well `paramiko` is pure python and that's the closest you'll get I guess (without reimplementing all it's ssh connectivity functionality).

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) which is pretty nice.

This allows you to ssh, telnet, etc. It also supports ftp which might be handy in transferring files.